# как правильно построить логику приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Я пишу приложение, но оно сейчас работает не правильно, постараюсь объяснить покороче. У меня есть главная коллекция в классе `Main`, она оперирует данные из класса `MainData`. Так же есть класс `Controller`, где в таблицу я передаю экземпляр класса `MainData`, и получается так, что каждый экземпляр класса - это одна строка в этой таблице. Идем далее, а далее у меня в этом же контроллере есть вторая таблица,  которая как и первая использует главную коллекцию из класса `Main`, которая (коллекция) как я и писал использует класс `MainData`, в котором есть своя коллекция где хранятся свои данные для второй таблицы. Так что именно работает не так, подозреваю, что из-за того, что две таблицы используют одну общую коллекцию, несмотря на то, что юзают свои переменные или коллекцию отображают всегда одинаковое количество строк, т.е. я создаю документ в первой таблице, вношу информацию в коллекцию которая отображается во второй таблице и получается так, что в двух таблицах всегда одинаковое количество строк, хотя по моем плану они не должны быть взаимосвязаны таким образом, а должно быть так, что если я создам 4 документа, и внесу 2 элемента в коллекцию для второй таблице, то при выделении первой таблицы (т.е. определенного документа созданного там), во второй отображаются только эти два документа. Так как должна быть построена логика в моем приложении?

Добавляю код `Main`

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage menuBar;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    /**
     * Данные, в виде наблюдаемого списка документов.
     */
    private ObservableList<MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Возвращает данные в виде наблюдаемого списка документов.
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<MainData> getContractData() {
        return contractData;
    }
//далее идут FXML-ки
```

`Controller`

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> contractTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, String> numberContractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, LocalDate> dateExecutionContractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, LocalDate> timeContractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> linkTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, ObservableList<String>> contractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, ObservableList<String>> linkColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label numberContractLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dateContractLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label counterpartyLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label subjectContractLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dateExecutionContractLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label timeContractLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label priceLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label priceOnlyLabel;


    // Ссылка на главное приложение.
    private Main main;

    /**
     * Конструктор.
     */
    public MainController() {
    }

    /**
     * Инициализация класса-контроллера.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Инициализация таблицы.
        numberContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().numberContractProperty());
        dateExecutionContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateExecutionContractProperty());
        timeContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().timeContractProperty());

        contractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameLink());

        // Очистка дополнительной информации об адресате.
        showContractDetails(null);

        // Слушаем изменения выбора, и при изменении отображаем
        // дополнительную информацию об адресате.
        contractTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showContractDetails(newValue));
    }

    /**
     * Вызывается главным приложением, которое даёт на себя ссылку.
     *
     * @param main
     */
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

        // Добавление в таблицу данных из наблюдаемого списка
        contractTable.setItems(main.getContractData());
        linkTable.setItems(main.getContractData());
    }

    /**
     * Заполняет все текстовые поля, отображая подробности об адресате.
     * Если указанный адресат = null, то все текстовые поля очищаются.
     *
     * @param mainData — адресат типа Person или null
     */
    private void showContractDetails(MainData mainData) {
        if (mainData != null) {
            // Заполняем метки информацией из объекта MainData.
            numberContractLabel.setText(mainData.getNumberContract());
            counterpartyLabel.setText(mainData.getCounterparty());
            subjectContractLabel.setText(mainData.getSubjectContract());
            priceLabel.setText(Integer.toString(mainData.getPrice()));
            priceOnlyLabel.setText(Integer.toString((mainData.getPrice() - mainData.getSumСostsInt())));

            dateContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getDateContract()));
            dateExecutionContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getDateExecutionContract()));
            timeContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getTimeContract()));

        } else {
            // Если Data = null, то убираем весь текст.
            numberContractLabel.setText("-");
            dateContractLabel.setText("-");
            counterpartyLabel.setText("-");
            subjectContractLabel.setText("-");
            dateExecutionContractLabel.setText("-");
            timeContractLabel.setText("-");
            priceLabel.setText("-");
            priceOnlyLabel.setText("-");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Создайте просто 2 коллекции). Также, у вас видимо внутрь коллекции передаются 1 и теже данные, которые поступают в обе таблицы одновременно. Чтобы было проще понять, приведите код из `Main` и `Controller`

Comment: @Dred добавил 2 класса

Comment: А вот теперь, ради эксперемента, сделайте так ` private ObservableList<MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MainData(/*ваш заполненный конструктор*/));` Я думаю вы увидете в обоих ваших таблицах 1 и тоже.

Comment: @Dred я использовал такой конструктор - `private ObservableList<MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MainData("123",
            LocalDate.of(1990,10,10), LocalDate.of(1990,10,10)));` и по сути ничего не поменялось

Comment: Хорошо... взгляните [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901765/9719337), возможно, это вам поможет. Именно на 2 ответ. Суть в том, что вы пытаетесь брать информацию из 1 объекта в 2 разных таблицы. Вы можете добавить Listener для вашей `contractData` и посмотреть, сколько выводов в sout вы будете получать при каждом изменении таблицы, естественно 2